# Spring batch JdbcPagingItemReader not able to read all events

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-batch

I had spring batch application like below (table name and query are edited for some general names)

when i execute this program, it was able to read 7500 events , i.e 3 times of chunk size and not able to read remaining records in oracle database. I had a table contain 50 million records and able to copy to another noSql database.

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MultiThreadPagingApp extends DefaultBatchConfigurer{

@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
public DataSource dataSource;

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@***********");
    dataSource.setUsername("user");
    dataSource.setPassword("password");

    return dataSource;
}


@Override
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {}

@Bean
@StepScope
ItemReader<UserModel> dbReader() throws Exception {

    JdbcPagingItemReader<UserModel> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<UserModel>();
    final SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean = new SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean();        
    sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setSelectClause("select * ");
    sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setFromClause("from user");
    sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setWhereClause("where id>0");
    sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setSortKey("name");
    reader.setQueryProvider(sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.getObject());
    reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    reader.setPageSize(2500);       
    reader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(UserModel.class));
    reader.afterPropertiesSet();
    reader.setSaveState(true);
    System.out.println("Reading users anonymized in chunks of {}"+ 2500);
    return reader;
}


@Bean
public Dbwriter writer() {
    return new Dbwriter(); // I had another class for this
}   

@Bean
public Step step1() throws Exception {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(4);
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
    taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();

    return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<UserModel, UserModel>chunk(2500)
            .reader(dbReader())
            .writer(writer())
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
            .build();
}


@Bean
public Job multithreadedJob() throws Exception {
    return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("multithreadedJob")
            .start(step1())
            .build();
} 


@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
    return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
}

@Bean
public JobRepository getJobRepo() throws Exception {
    return new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(getTransactionManager()).getObject();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MultiThreadPagingApp.class, args);
}
```

}

Can you help me how can i efficiently read all the records using spring batch, or help me any other approach to handle this. I had tried one approch mentioned here : http://techdive.in/java/jdbc-handling-huge-resultset
its taken 120 mins to read and save all records with single thread application. Since spring batch is best fit for this, I assume we can handle this scenario in quick time.

Comment: why it doesn't complete the job? does it throw an exception, we need more information

Comment: It doesn't throws any exception. Its just finishes job my reading three times of chunk size and stopped. here is logs:                                                         Job: [SimpleJob: [name=multithreadedJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{}]
INFO 15008 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step1]
  INFO 15008 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=multithreadedJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the `saveState` flag to true (BTW, it should be set before calling `afterPropertiesSet`) on a `JdbcPagingItemReader` and using this reader in a multithreaded step. However, [it is documented](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcPagingItemReader.java#L65-L70) to set this flag to false in a multi-threaded context.

Multi-threading with database readers is usually not the best option, I would recommend to use partitioning in your case.

Comment: I had set saveState flag to false and moved that flag before calling afterPropertiesSet. Still I am having same issue and its reading only three times of chunk size.  and , Data in table is not having any way to separate data based on some condition, there is no primary key as well in that table. How can I read those kind of data from DB using partition approach ?

Comment: in your where clause you have `where id>0`, so you can create a partitioner that partitions data based on this id. Take a look at the [ColumnRangePartitioner](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/common/ColumnRangePartitioner.java) as an example.

Comment: i had tried like that , unfortunately in our DB, we have no such primary/unique key defined. this Id's are some distinct numbers from one to ten. all records having this numbers. like each 1 to 40 million records having same Id. some of them having less count and some of them having more records.I don't have any specific unique column for that table. Not exactly sure how can i read complete table having this kind of data.apart from ID value all other columns can accept null values. and this ID values are present but not unique for each row. Please help me.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine - Even if we use `Partitions` with`JdbcPagingItemReader` giving me less records than anticipated, I am loosing almost 200 thousand records.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i fix it by changing my sortKey. I realize that the previous one wasn't different for every data records. So i replace it with ID whitch were different for every records of the Database

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).